# 'System.IDisposable ServiceStack.JsonHttpClient::__requestAccess()' in assembly

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, visual-studio-2017, servicestack

I am using servicestack in one of my Xamarin Android project. Its all working fine if use **Linking** = '*None*' in Android Options. If I change **Linking** = '*Sdk Assemblies Only*' application is not building and its showing below error.

```
Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State
Error The "LinkAssemblies" task failed unexpectedly.
Mono.Linker.MarkException: Error processing method: 'System.IDisposable ServiceStack.JsonHttpClient::__requestAccess()' in assembly: 
'ServiceStack.HttpClient.dll' ---> Mono.Cecil.ResolutionException: Failed to resolve System.IDisposable ServiceStack.LicenseUtils::RequestAccess(System.Object,ServiceStack.LicenseFeature,ServiceStack.LicenseFeature)
at Mono.Linker.Steps.MarkStep.HandleUnresolvedMethod(MethodReference reference)
at Mono.Linker.Steps.MarkStep.MarkMethod(MethodReference reference)
at Mono.Linker.Steps.MarkStep.MarkInstruction(Instruction instruction)
at Mono.Linker.Steps.MarkStep.MarkMethodBody(MethodBody body)
at Mono.Linker.Steps.MarkStep.ProcessMethod(MethodDefinition method)
at Mono.Linker.Steps.MarkStep.ProcessQueue()
--- End of inner exception stack trace ---
at Mono.Linker.Steps.MarkStep.ProcessQueue()
at Mono.Linker.Steps.MarkStep.ProcessPrimaryQueue()
at Mono.Linker.Steps.MarkStep.Process()
at MonoDroid.Tuner.MonoDroidMarkStep.Process(LinkContext context)
at Mono.Linker.Pipeline.Process(LinkContext context)
at MonoDroid.Tuner.Linker.Process(LinkerOptions options, ILogger logger, LinkContext& context)
at Xamarin.Android.Tasks.LinkAssemblies.Execute(DirectoryAssemblyResolver res)
at Xamarin.Android.Tasks.LinkAssemblies.Execute()
at Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskExecutionHost.Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.ITaskExecutionHost.Execute()
at Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskBuilder.<ExecuteInstantiatedTask>d__26.MoveNext() MY.XForms.Droid
```

Can any one help me out from this. 
TIA.

Comment: About  Linking = 'Sdk Assemblies Only', I find one thread, it says that you can go into your build folder, copy all the names of all the assemblies minus extension and add them to the "Skip linking assemblies" field, about this, you can take a look:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52972017/how-to-resolve-xamarin-android-linking-problem